# Google analytics event traking error?

Tags: drupal, google-analytics, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am install Google Analytics module in drupal 7. I have add a tag onClick.

```
onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Video', 'Play','content title');";
```

using this code and i have click this link.

```
Error : Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined.
```

How to fix this error.thanks for your feature help!

Comment: Have you checked source of page, does it contain google analytics script?

Comment: thanks for your replay but i have check my source code my tracking code appear in site header

Comment: can you post in your question the google analytics code from header? It looks like ga is not defined there.

Comment: how to define ga in my tracking code

Comment: show that code from header please. I need to see how your google analytics code looks like.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i["GoogleAnalyticsObject"]=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,"script","//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js","ga");ga("create", "UA-68795707-1", {"cookieDomain":"auto"});ga("set", "anonymizeIp", true);ga("send", "pageview");
</script>

Comment: Can you check if google analytics library is loaded and is not blocked by your browser?
What module do you use?

Comment: Google Analytics module

Comment: thanks for your feedback google tracking code is working fine.once again thanks